# splitting multiple lines using str.split

Tags: python

Trying to split a multiline paragraph using str.split single line split works correctly. Is str.split the correct way to split multiple lines what am I missing here?
single line split working correctly example:

```
dmap_lines = """Nople Normal Altar1-truck-Altar2,Altar2-train-Cansomme,Cansomme-flight-Karoh,Karoh-truck-Nople"""
destinations = []
remainders1 = []
stages = []
for line in dmap_lines:
    destination, remainder1, remainder = dmap_lines.split(' ')
    destinations.append(destination)
    remainders1.append(remainder1)
    remainder = remainder.split(',')
    stages.append(remainder)
print(destination)
print(remainder1)
print(type(remainder))
print(remainder)

Expected Output: 
Nople
Normal
<class 'list'>
['Altar1-truck-Altar2', 'Altar2-train-Cansomme', 'Cansomme-flight-Karoh', 'Karoh-truck-Nople']
```

with multiline code:

```
dmap_lines = """Nople Normal Altar1-truck-Altar2,Altar2-train-Cansomme,Cansomme-flight-Karoh,Karoh-truck-Nople\nDria Normal Altar1-truck-Altar2,Altar2-train-Mala1,Mala1-truck-Mala2,Mala2-flight-Dria"""
destinations = []
remainders1 = []
stages = []
for line in dmap_lines:
    destination, remainder1, remainder = dmap_lines.split(' ')
    destinations.append(destination)
    remainders1.append(remainder1)
    remainder = remainder.split(',')
    stages.append(remainder)
print(destination)
print(remainder1)
print(type(remainder))
print(remainder)

Receiving error in output: 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-78-9eb9f8fa1c64> in <module>
      4 stages = []
      5 for line in dmap_lines:
----> 6     destination, remainder1, remainder = dmap_lines.split(' ')
      7     destinations.append(destination)
      8     remainders1.append(remainder1)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

Expected output:

```
Nople
Normal
<class 'list'>
['Altar1-truck-Altar2', 'Altar2-train-Cansomme', 'Cansomme-flight-Karoh', 'Karoh-truck-Nople']

Dria
Normal
<class 'list'>
['Altar1-truck-Altar2,Altar2-train-Mala1,Mala1-truck-Mala2,Mala2-flight-Dria']
```

Why is the for loop not iterating over multiple lines and splitting the string into the sections?

Comment: In your second example, there are six ` ` (space) characters in the string, which it's trying to unpack to only three variables. Did you mean to do `for line in dmap_lines.split('\n'):`, to split the string on each linefeed?

Comment: @Green Cloak Guy  the buffer  contents for each line are location  deliverytype  <delivery route comma seperated> I am looking to split each line from the dmap_lines to seperate the contents actual line has only one space character six space characters are not there in the string

Comment: have not added 6 spaces  no idea how the 6 spaces have got added

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason why `re.findall` would not be a better approach here:

```py
dmap_lines = "Nople Normal Altar1-truck-Altar2,Altar2-train-Cansomme,Cansomme-flight-Karoh,Karoh-truck-Nople"
matches = re.findall(r'\b\w+-\w+-\w+\b', dmap_lines)
print(matches)
```

This prints:

```
['Altar1-truck-Altar2', 'Altar2-train-Cansomme', 'Cansomme-flight-Karoh',
 'Karoh-truck-Nople']
```

To get a single CSV string, use `join`:

```py
csv = ','.join(matches)
print(csv)
```

This prints:

```
Altar1-truck-Altar2,Altar2-train-Cansomme,Cansomme-flight-Karoh,Karoh-truck-Nople
```

Comment: only the section of stages is split each line contains a location deliverytype delivery stages  The idea is to get the location and delivery type seperated from delivery stages.

Comment: I am not able to understand why the for loop is not working on both the lines equally

Comment: You gave us a single line input and I don't understand where multiline issues come into play here.  Can you edit your question and reveal the actual problem?